# Scout: limit the input SCSS file

Tags: sass

When using Scout, is there a way to prevent it from compiling every SCSS file? I use one main SCSS file to import all dependency SCSS, thus only need the one CSS file output, as opposed to one CSS for each SCSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files prefixed with an underscore do not get compiled to a CSS file.  This is a standard Sass feature.  Only the first file listed here will have a corresponding CSS file generated:

```
i-am-compiled.scss
_i-am-not-compiled.scss
_i-am-also-not-compiled.scss
```